# No additional drivers for Intel HD Graphics 400 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: intel-graphics

I can't find nothing in additional drivers list in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

My computer have Intel HD graphic Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 400 (Braswell)

Here's a screenshot from my `Additional drivers` menu.

[image: screenshot]

What driver should be used in my device?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the graphics cards has drivers build-in into Linux kernel. Especially Intel GPUs don't have proprietary drivers shipped separately. Well, there was an update tool from Intel for a while, but it was discontinued some time ago. So basically you're using the driver built-in into Linux kernel.

If you want to check what driver is used please open the [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) from `Applications Menu`.

You can also summon the terminal using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Then type:

```
lspci -v
```

and look for anything with string "VGA"

You can also try this command to print only "VGA" related items:

```
lspci -v | sed -n '/^[0-9].*VGA/,/^$/p'
```

and look for lines starting with `Kernel driver in use` and `Kernel modules`. This will give you an idea on which driver is currently in use.